# Is there a way to iterate a Path object on Android?

Tags: android

Given a `android.graphics.Path`, I would like to be able to retrieve the specific path commands: the quadTo(..), curveTo(...), lineTo(...), etc., that the Path is composed of.

Java provides a PathIterator to accomplish this for GeneralPath objects, but I haven't found any equivalent for Android. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked the [actual implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/graphics/Path.java#Path.addArc%28android.graphics.RectF,float,float%29) and it doesn't look like you can get the information. Every call just goes down to native code, and the actual path is stored on the native side.

I also tried looking at Canvas's drawPath method, but it just drops to native code as well.

I'm not sure if it's possible in your code, but your best option looks like sub-classing Path and overriding all the adXXX methods to store the values in a list.

Comment: Any follow-up 9 years later? It seems a basic rule of programming "Thou Shalt Get Everything Thou Set," even if just for such mundane tasks as ripping the points out of the path to put them into an SVG <polyline>, but still...

Answer (score 7):

It is now possible in 3 different ways:

- On Android U, with `Path.getPathIterator` (see [PathIterator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathIterator))
- Using [pathway](https://github.com/romainguy/pathway), an Open Source library available all the way back to API 21
- Using [androidx.graphics:graphics-path](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/graphics#graphics-path-1.0.0-alpha01), the `androidx` port of `pathway`

Sorry it took so long!

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I wanted it to have the answer
You cannot retrieve the commands but you can get points back.
Look at `android.graphics.PathMeasure` API  1

```
  float[] tmpPos = new float[2];
  float[] tmpTan = new float[2];
  PathMeasure measure = new PathMeasure();
  measure.setPath(path, true);
  do {
   float dist = measure.getLength();
   for (float p = 0; p < dist; p += 1) {
     measure.getPosTan(p, tmpPos, tmpTan);
     float x = tmpPos[0], y = tmpPos[1];
     float nx = tmpTan[0], ny = tmpTan[1];
     // do your own stuff
    }
 } while (measure.nextContour());
```

PathMeasure also has getSegment It may be use to extract the segment but I have never tried that.